# Why is the previously inserted text reset after using an arrow key?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, register

From help `:help i_ctrl-a`:

```
CTRL-A      Insert previously inserted text.  {not in Vi}
```

Let's say I have an empty buffer and I'm in normal mode.
I type `i` to go in insert mode.
I type `()`, then move the cursor one character to the left by hitting `<C-h>` (which I mapped to `<left>` in insert mode), type `foo`,  and go back in normal mode by hitting escape.

The buffer contains: `(foo)`
I thought, wrongly, that the previously inserted text would be `(foo)` but it's not.
The previously inserted text is only `foo` which can be checked by typing `:registers .` or hitting `<C-a>` in insert mode again.

Why does hitting an arrow key reset the previously inserted text ?
Is there a way to make the dot register store all the text that was inserted the last time I went in insert mode even though I hit an arrow key ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In insert mode, the left arrow key actually exits insert mode, moves the cursor, then re-enters insert mode. That breaks your change into two changes: inserting `()` and inserting `foo`. This behavior is discussed under

```
:help ins-special-special
```

The solution is to remap the left arrow key to include `CTRL-G U`. The example in the Vim Reference Manual is hard to find because it's not directly tagged. First go to

```
:help i_CTRL-G_U
```

then scroll down 42 lines to "An example for using `CTRL-G U`:" For the left arrow key, use this mapping:

```
inoremap <Left> <C-G>U<Left>
```

It seems to work, but the display of the `.` register by the `:registers` command looks weird after executing your `(foo)` example. On my Windows machine, it looks like this:

```
".  ()^GU<80>klfoo
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! That was bothering me since a long time, and never found the solution. I modified my vimrc with `inoremap <C-h> <C-g>U<Left>` and `inoremap <C-l> <C-g>U<Right>` and your solution works perfectly ! By the way, on my linux machine I've got the same weird output as you for the `:registers` command, so it's not coming from windows.

Comment: `<c-g>U` came with a recent patch. That may explain why you missed it so far.

Comment: Do you think there's a way to make it work with Ctrl+Right/Left as well? I tried analogous mappings but they don't seem to work.