# How to test if Vim supports <C-g>U?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

I would like to make some modification to the code of [this plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi).

It adds / changes some default keybindings. Among them are `<C-b>` and `<C-f>` which move the cursor one character to the left / right.

The problem is they [break the undo sequence](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/why-is-the-previously-inserted-text-reset-after-using-an-arrow-key), because they are mapped to `<Left>` and `<Right>`. The [solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5914/4939) is to prefix them with `<C-g>U`.

However, I don't know in which version and which patch `<C-g>U` appeared in Vim.

I tried `:helpgrep CTRL-G.*U` which gave me 5 results in the quickfix list, but none of them gave me the info.

So I have 2 questions:

- How can I find precisely when `<C-g>U` appeared in Vim?
- How can I reliably test in a script if vim supports it?

Let's say I find out that `<C-g>U` appeared in Vim 7.4.567, would the following line be the proper way to test?:

```
if v:version > 704 || v:version == 704 && has("patch567")
```

Comment: I use `if (v:version == 704 && has("patch393")) || v:version > 704` with `set renderoptions` and seems to work pretty well.

Comment: For the 1st issue, i used Google :D https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/uZbngIYTl5M

Comment: Thank you very much! So I just need to find out when `<C-g>U` was added...

Comment: Ah ok so it was in patch 849, thank you very much again. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Could you briefly explain how you found it on vim_dev ? I'm not used to this site.

Comment: romainl's answer is ok - i just used quoted text from the relevant vim's help section to search on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all the patches [on Vim's FTP server](http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/). `<C-g>U` was added in [patch 7.4.849](http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/7.4.849).

Answer (score 4):

I simply use `has('patch-7.4.849')` in lh-brackets. This is enough.